# Is there is any name of the adjacence matrix constructed in such way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, quaternions, research

I have constructed an adjacence matrix for a non-conjugate graph of a generalized quaternion group.In this matrix if two elements which are conjugate to each other are operated gives "0" other they gives "1". I am in search of the name of such kind of matrix.

Comment: Did you mean to say *adjacency matrix* when you typed *adjacence matrix*, @Mathematics?

Comment: You aren't looking for a specific matrix but for a matrix **up to reordering**. Unless you rank the group elements in a specific order...

Comment: My guess is this is not a standard enough thing to have a name, but if you want to call it something, maybe something like "non-conjugate incidence matrix" or "conjugate anti-incidence matrix".